# Checking whether two or more consecutive letters are uppercase

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to create a function in Ruby that checks whether a string has two or more consecutive uppercase letters, example:

```
"Hello There"  # => returns false
"Hello ThERe"  # => returns true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"Hello There" =~ /[A-Z]{2}/
# => nil

"Hello ThERe" =~ /[A-Z]{2}/
# => 8
```

This will return nil if it doesn't have the letters, or an index of the first occurence otherwise (you can treat these as true/false)

```
def has_two_uppercase_letters
  str =~ /[A-Z]{2}/
end
```

Or if you want to return an explicit true/false:

```
def has_two_uppercase_letters
  (str =~ /[A-Z]{2}/) != nil
end
```

Comment: If the match index is zero, is this still evaluated as TRUE?

Comment: Yes. Only `nil` and `false` evaluate as false. Everything else (including 0) evaluates as true. See my edited answer.

Comment: Fails on `el ÁGuila`. Also fails on `ⅩⅦ`.

Answer (score 4):

```
string =~ /[A-Z]{2,}/
```

Match in the set "A" to "Z" 2 or more times.

You can test this on http://rubular.com/

Comment: It works, but there's no need to detect more than two. Detecting two is sufficient.

Comment: Good point, @sawa. @dmarkow's answer is more apt. But Rubular is a good resource for regex testing.

Comment: I like rubular too. It is convenient.

Comment: Fails on `la niÑA`. Also fails on `© ⅯⅯⅪ`.  Also fails on `ÆGypt`.

Answer (score 3):

Because Ruby doesn’t support `\p{upper}`, you have to use

```
/\p{Lu}{2,}/
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: pik ruby -e "p 'MMXII' =~ /\p{Lu}{2,}/" ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]

-e:1: warning: regexp has invalid interval
-e:1: warning: regexp has `}' without escape
nil

ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

-e:1: invalid character property name {Lu}: /\p{Lu}{2,}/

Comment: @bheeshmar: How can Ruby 1.9 not support the Unicode general categories as property names? According to the Oniguruma docs, which I believe Ruby (strangely) uses instead of PCRE, you should have them.